# Leitura XML em VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, xmldocument, xml-schema

Bom dia senhores, estou com uma dificuldade em ler alguns campos do XML. Por exemplo, estou desenvolvendo um software de vendas e no momento da leitura do XML para impressão ele está puxando apenas um item ao invés de todos. O XML em si possuí 3 itens porém quando mando imprimir na impressora vem apenas 1. 
Segue abaixo a estrutura do meu código no VB.NET, quem puder me ajudar eu irei ficar imensamente agradecido.

```
/Lendo o Xml
Dim produto As New BindingSource
        produto.DataSource = ds
        produto.DataMember = "det"
        produto.DataMember = "prod"
        Dim descricao As String = produto.Current("xProd").ToString()
        Dim quantidade As String = produto.Current("qCom").ToString()
        Dim valorprod As String = produto.Current("vProd").ToString()

/Imprimindo o XML
escreve.Write("#  Descricao           Qtde X Preco      Total" & vbNewLine)
        escreve.Write("------------------------------------------------" + vbNewLine)
        escreve.Write("" + descricao + "    " + quantidade + " X " + valorprod + "    " + valorprod & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
```

Comment: Dá para ver a estrutura do XML? Um exemplo?

Comment: <det nItem="1">
<prod>
<cProd>7898577370182</cProd>
<xProd>J.WATANABE/COUVE MANTE</xProd>                            
</prod>                                 
<det nItem="2">
<prod>
<cProd>66396</cProd>
<xProd>GRANEL/ALHO KG</xProd>                                                                </prod>                                                                                               
</det>

Comment: Matheus, tem vários exemplos de XML com VB.Net lá no VBMania... já tentou rodar algum? Por favor, pode me pontuar no outro tópico que eu te ajudei com a impressora Epson TM T20?